# Why am I unable to choose myself as the Active Directory admin for Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

In MSSM I want to try to connect to my Azure database using Active Directory - Integrated authentication.

I am using windows 10 logging into Windows 10 with my email address, thus my email address.

In the Azure portal I also login with my email address

```
Under Home->SQL servers -> myserver - Active Directory admin -> Add admin
```

my email is disabled as a possible selection.

Why?

Comment: Read this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/working-azure-active-directory-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Is your account perhaps a personal Microsoft account?

Comment: Ah, it is a personal account with the same domain name as the AD. Is that why then?